# Can we draw a RB tree with 8 black nodes and 12 red nodes?

Tags: graph-theory, red-black-tree

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898523/how-to-tell-whether-a-red-black-tree-can-have-x-black-nodes-and-y-red-nodes-or-n) on stackoverflow, but it wasn't answered (clearly).

I can try and construct such tree (8 black nodes and 12 red nodes) without voiding any of the 5 RB-trees (so far I haven't been able to do that though);

1. A node is either red or black
2. The root is black
3. All leaves are black
4. Both children of every red node are black
5. Every simple path from a given node to any of its descendant leaves contains the same number of black nodse.

But I'm really interested in a more elegant answer (other than try and see if it works).

Edited: In the case of where the leaves  are counted as blacks, it's obvious that such tree is impossible to construct. But what about if leaves are not counted as Black nodes (8 non-leaf nodes)

Answer (score 0):

It follows from rule 3 and 4 that there can't be more red than black nodes, as adding red nodes to the tree necessarily adds black nodes. This is if you count the leaves of a rb tree as nodes(your definitions do).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my question to make it clearer. I'm more concerned about the case where leaves (null pointers) are not counted in the 8 black nodes

Comment: There can't be more red than black nodes?
What about 
     2
1/    \3
where 1 & 3 are red, 2 is black? There are other trees as well where red exceeds black. 2 is the root node.

Comment: @SJHowe "3. All leaves are black"